# Hide Status Bar In certain View controllers *Specific*

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a very specific question concerning hiding status bar.
I incorporated the code below to easily get a status bar on every view controller, but I have a cameraViewcontroller where I don't want a status bar. I'm trying to  hide the status bar.

```
//change the statusbar color for all view controllers
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

I tried using

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

and

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

    return true
}
```

but none of this seems to work. I'm new to programming and stack overflow so please help me out. I tried search for the answer but can't seem to find the answer to this particular dilemma. Your help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

its works for me perfectly.

**Objective-C**

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
}
```

**you should also use info.plist**

"View controller-based status bar appearance" set to NO

"Status bar is initially hidden" set to YES

Comment: is having application.statusBarstyle = .lightcontent in "AppDelegate" causing this problem? Because the status bar is still in CameraViewController. I have "view controller-based status bar appearance" already set to NO. When I set "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES, I lose all my status bar on other view controllers.

Comment: "statusBarStyle" Deprecated: IOS 9.0 @KennyHo

Comment: So from my understanding, your way using Swift, you would have to code that for all the view controllers. Is there not a way to do something similar to statusBarStyle that automatically adds a status bar to all my view controllers? Then I only have to get rid of one status bar for the CameraVC.

Comment: you also use " override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {return .lightContent} " change StatusBarStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply below code in the CameraVC :

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```